# How can I convert an array of objects into single object while keys of all the objects are same and value may differ

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to convert:

```js
var arr = [{ "name": "value1" }, { "name": "value2" }, { "name": "value3" }];
var obj = {}; //create the empty output object

arr.forEach(function (item, i) {                                                    
  var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; 
  obj[key] = item[key];  
});                                 

console.log("obj",obj);
```

this will give me only last object as `{name: "value3"}`

the expected Result will be:

```
{ name: "value1", name : "value2", name: "value3" }
```

Comment: Your desired result is not valid.  A key in an object cannot repeat.  At best it would have to be `{name:["value1", "value 2", "value 3"]}`

Comment: What would be the use-case for that data structure?

Comment: As @Taplar mentioned, you can't have more than one value for a given key in a JavaScript object. Even if that was possible, it wouldn't be very useful...

Comment: the expected result is'n impossible, because keys of object must be unique.

Comment: @FranjoPintarić i have user details and i want to send all details of all users as mail in this case all users have same fields..and i want to convert the array of user objects into one object and send them as one object

Comment: Your expected result is an object which will simply take name:"value3"  any ways, so that it looks like {name:"value3"} if you output it. because obj is simply overriding obj.name to "value3". Any use case :)

Answer (score 0):

Per a comment above, your desired output object cannot have duplicate properties and can be in an array instead.

```
const arr = [{ "name": "value1" }, { "name": "value2" }, { "name": "value3" }];

const output = {};

// Iterate through each object in your array
arr.forEach(object => { 
  // For each entry in your object, in this case we only have name
  for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
   
    // If the key's value isn't an array, we will assign a new one
    if(!Array.isArray(output[key])) {
      output[key] = [];
    }

    // Push the value to the output object key's array
    output[key].push(value);
  }
});

// Expected { name: ["value1", "value2", "value3"] }
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

ES6 symbols can be used as same property name to Objects. However every Symbol is unique. Right now the only solution I could find for your Question is using Symbol as our key. Because in general Objects cannot have two same keys.

See if the below code can help.

```
const arrQuestion = [{ "name": "value1" }, { "name": "value2" }, { "name": "value3" 
}];


const ourObj = {};

arrQuestion.forEach(obj => {
 let symbol = Symbol("name");
 ourObj[symbol] = obj.name;
});

console.log(ourObj);
```

[image]

Hope this helps :)